# CloudKit Login Missing Acount

Tags: cloudkit

When a user is not signed to Game Center a UI pops up in the app.  If a user is logged in to iCloud the app gets the cloudkit user ID.  However, I do not understand what happens if the user is not logged in to iCLoud at all.  As far as I can tell the app does not promt the user.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 0):

You have to test for that yourself and take the appropriate actions. For testing the status you can use the code below. At the line where the account status is logged you could show an alert where you point the user to the settings app.

```
container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
database = container.publicCloudDatabase
container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler({status, error in
    if error != nil {
        NSLog("Error: Initialising EVCloudKitDao - accountStatusWithCompletionHandler.\n\(error!.description)")
    } else {
        self.accountStatus = status
    }
    NSLog("Account status = \(status.hashValue) (0=CouldNotDetermine/1=Available/2=Restricted/3=NoAccount)")
})
NSLog("Container identifier = \(container.containerIdentifier)")
```

The code above is a snippet from [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao)